# SE Uploader puts row of control objects on several lines

Tags: support

I have just posted [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUXOo.png). When uploading the image I noticed that a row of control objects are put on several lines in the image. In my notebook they are on one line. Not a major problem but is it possible to get the true image?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not a bug. It's the inherent behavior of `Row` that is messing it up. What happens is that the Uploader sends your whole cell into a new, invisible notebook and renders it into an image. Your expression doesn't fit into the width of the background notebook and therefore the controls are broken into the next line.

The fix is to use

```
Grid[{{Button...}}]
```

instead of `Row`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know the size of the invisible notebook? Presumably if we target that size then we won't get this problem.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/blob/master/SETools/SEUploader.m#L346-L361). The width is fixed to a maximum of 650px to make it not too large for the website.